# laravel relation data to search for other models

Tags: laravel, relationship

`Client` model has relations to `Invoice`. I need to get the amounts from the `Invoice` relationship and find the matching transactions from the `Transaction` model.

I do it like this:

```php
class Client extends Model
{
    public function invoices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Invoice::class);
    }
    
    public function priceInvoices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Invoice::class)->select('gross_price');
    }
}
```

```php
foreach (Client::find($id)->priceInvoices->toArray() as $item) {
    $prices[] = $item['gross_price'];
}

$transactions_for_prices = Transaction::whereIn('price', $prices)->get();
```

Will it be possible to make it more elegant?

Answer (score 0):

If your Invoice.php Model has a relationship with a Transaction.php Model,
Example:

```php
class Invoice extends Model
{
    public function trasnactions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class);
    }
    
}
```

You could do something like this in a controller. (example)

```php
public function show($id) {
    $client = Client::findOrFail($id);
    return view('view_name', [
        'client' => $client,
        'transactions => $client->invoices->transactions
    ]);
}
```